# How to add new blank row in the middle of text in Google Docs when using gspread module for python?

Tags: python, gspread

I tried to insert a new blank row example after 8 rows with `insert_row` or `append_row` or `add_row`, but they only add a new row in the end of the sheet.

My question is how to correctly insert the row ?

Also, I read [documentation](http://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html?highlight=row) didn't find the needed class.

Comment: Well, `add_row` is designed to add extra rows to the end of the sheet (which by default only contains 1000 rows). As to the other part of your question, it's impossible to answer without seeing your code and data. If you're uploading a list, why not just insert empty strings at the desired indices? Or just `insert_row` with a list of empty strings.

Answer (score 1):

[Worksheet.insert_row()](http://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html?highlight=row#gspread.Worksheet.insert_row) is the way to go

Notice that you must supply the index for where the rows will be inserted.

As for how to insert a certain number of rows your best bet is to use a for loop:

```
empty_row = ['' for cell in range(Worksheet.col_count)]
insertion_row = 4
number_of_rows = 8
for row in range(number_of_rows):
    Worksheet.insert_row(empty_row,index=insertion_row)
```

Note that this will have to make as many API calls as the number of rows that you want to add and currently the insert_rows function is notoriously slow.

Comment: Just tested this and unfortunatly it doesn't work. If, instead you use '~' or anouther visible char then it works but this defeats the point of the empty ''